# How to integrate a non-model radio button element to a CActiveForm in Yii?

Tags: forms, yii, radio-button

In a Yii application, I'm working on, there is a simple `CActiveForm`, where all elements are model related and look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'foo'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'foo', array(/* HTML options */)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'foo'); ?>
</div>
```

Now I want to implement following case:

The should be a `radio button` element `bar` with two options. Depending on the selected option different form elements should be displayed (a dropdown list with existing `bar`-entries oder a set of field to create a new one). In the controller I want to analyze the field `bar` and, if needed (means e.g. if `bar == 1`) use the provided field set to create a new table entry.

`CActiveForm#radioButton(...)` needs a model as input. But for this case the model is not relevant -- the radio button I need should only contain/provide the information, how the data has to be processed. Is there a Yii conform way to implement this requirement and create a "non-model" form element for a Yii `CActiveForm`?

Comment: Create one member variable in model class $bar and used it as model form element. Otherwise use CHtml::radiobutttonList();

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 1. A member variable `$bar` would be a very simple solution, but actually it's a bit dirty, since this `$bar` is only used for data processing in the controller and has nothin to do with the model. 2. `CHtml::radiobutttonList();` -- How can I add such an element to the form?

Comment: `<?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList('bar', 'first Value', array(1 => 'first Value',2 => 'Second Value'));?> ` In between CActiveForm and endWidget()

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Can I integrate this "manually" created form elemtn to my form object, so that it gets validated with the other elements? Or does only work for elements comming from a model?